# why isn't my javascript function not being called

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Working with MVC

view:

```
<a onlick="getMembershipDetails('@memberships.OrderTemplateId', '@Url.Action("GetMembershipContractDetails","MembersA")');" class="cw-grid-link">Details</a><br/>
```

Javascript function:

```
   function getMembershipDetails(orderTemplateId, url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data:{
            orderTemplateId: orderTemplateId
        },
        success: function (html) {
            //$("#search-structure-target").html(html);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(html))
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        traditional: true
    });
}
```

Controller method which should be called:

```
public ActionResult GetMembershipContractDetails(string orderTemplateId)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderTemplateId))
            return null;
        var details = userOrganisationProvider.GetOrgFinSupportDetail(SelectedOrganisation, orderTemplateId);

        return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

For some reason my javascript function above is not being called. All the other similar functions work/get called except this one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: escape string in you html.

Comment: `onlick` mistyped?

Comment: onlick should ob onclick

Comment: FFS!! thanks @emil and caramiriel I didn't notice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called another function and have another one.

See: you call `getMembershipDetails` but the name of your function is `GetOrderFinancialDetails`

```
<a onclick="GetOrderFinancialDetails('@memberships.OrderTemplateId', '@Url.Action("GetMembershipContractDetails","MembersA")');" class="cw-grid-link">Details</a><br/>
```

**EDITED:** As has been said in the comments, change `onlick` to `onclick`.